# Run an "After Effects" script without GUI

Tags: javascript, command-line, extendscript, after-effects

I want to run a script in After Effects without launching the GUI. But at the moment I'm getting an error. This is in After Effects version CC 2017. Windows operating system. I ran this command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe After Effects CC 2017\Support Files\AfterFX.exe" -noui -r "D:\AEScripts\Render\SampleScript.jsx"
```

If I use the following command, After Effects executes it (with GUI) and displays the alert, as expected.

```
"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe After Effects CC 2017\Support Files\AfterFX.exe" -s "alert('Hello World')"
```

Anyone run into a similar problem?

UPDATE:
There is no error. After Effects runs (as seen in the Task Manager), but then closes. The script is supposed to open a project, edit it and close it. When the project is opened after running the script (through command line), it remains unedited.

When the script is run with the GUI (through command line), the script works, but then this error message is displayed:

```
After Effects error: Crash in progress. Last logged message was: <6004> <BEE_WorkQueue> <5> BEE_WorkQueue_PreCloseProject end
```

The script works perfectly when it is run manually (through After Effects).

Here is the sample script I tested with, if you need it:

```
app.open(new File("C:/test/test-cc2017.aep"));
var proj = app.project;
var myComp = proj.items.addComp("Nice", 1920, 1080, 1, 10, 30);
myComp.layers.addText("Completed");
proj.close(CloseOptions.SAVE_CHANGES) ;
```

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting? Bit hard to tell what's going on without it.

Comment: It appear to me to be a bug, and it has been around for a while. If you can access Mac you can possible run apple-scripts this way, but on Windows AE will crash...

Comment: Thanks. It looks like Mac is the only way to go.

Comment: Anyway, this -noui has nothing to do else to create crashes..